# Menubar width issue in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi everyone i have created a navigation bar in wordpress but i don't know how to increase the width of that each nav 
can anyone help me

css:

```
.navbar-default{
    margin:0px !important;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a, .header-qlinks a.hlnk-qlinks {
    color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    background: #352808;
}
```

code generated through wordpress:

```
<?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'              => 'primary',
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
        ?>
```

[image]

i need to change the width of each redmarked area

if u want more infromation visit http://demo.seyali.com/skv_new_wp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your query is you want to increase width of each navigation list item..

Here's how you can do it in your code :

**1. Change width of all the elements -**

```
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px; //To add 20px padding on left and right side
}
```

or

```
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: left;
  min-width: 150px; //specify proper min width.. 
}
```

**2. If you want to add width of only first element (under red box)**

```
.navbar-nav>li:first-child {
  min-width: 150px; //specify proper min width.. 
}
```

or

```
.navbar-nav>li:first-child {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px; //To add 20px padding on left and right side
}
```

Comment: @user3593694 Note that this will increase ALL of the nav elements in the menu. If you need to target that individual menu element you will need to give it a class.

Comment: He wants to add width for first element only? He's not clear about that.. @mrbubbles

Comment: We've given solutions for both eventualities.

Comment: i need to increase a  width for each and every  elements

Comment: I have given the solution. Try first solution then :-) If that solves your problem, mark it as answer to help others in community. 

Regards...

Comment: Also, if you need to support older browsers than IE9 the :first-child selector does not work.

Comment: bootstrap style might be overriding the property.. Try replacing .navbar-nav with '#menu-primary'

Comment: sorry i had done a simple mistake ,padding worked thanks....................@mrbubbles

Answer (score 0):

You can provide `width` for `.navbar-nav>li` class in `bootstrap.min.css`

```
.navbar-nav>li {
     width: 140px;  //your required width
   }
```

**Note**: this affect all `li.`
or you can provide class for each `li` and then provide different `width` for each `li`.

**OR**

increase `padding` for `#menu-primary > li > a` in `style.css`

```
#menu-primary > li > a {
padding: 15px 15px 15px;
margin: 1px;
}
```

**Note**: this affect all `li a.`
Here also  you can provide class for each `anchor tag` and then provide different `padding` for each `anchor.`